# Mostly private methods

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to define methods that are private most of the time, but not always. For example:

```
class Service

    def initialize(repo)
      @repo = repo
    end

    private def repo
      @repo
    end

    def all
      repo.all
    end
end
```

My class `Service` will implement features around a repository object. I want to completely hide away the `repo` object to prevent its leakage to my production code.

However when debugging or testing I want to be lazy and call `service.repo` directly instead using `service.send :repo`.

I thought about loading a class extension or dirty ENV var check for my tests and console, however that **prevents my tests from breaking** if code inside `./lib/*` makes bad use of private methods during a test run.

Now I am exploring with refinements, but that requires too much boilerplate and I want to do some decorator like this:

```
+LibPrivate
def repo
  @repo
end
```

That is a [Python like decorator](https://github.com/michaelfairley/method_decorators), but I believe since Ruby 2.1 it might be possible to define custom modifiers beyond private/public without that gem

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the visibility of the method in your test helper or in your test file.

```
Service.class_eval do
  public :repo
end
```

Just keep in mind that private method are in theory implementation details. You should not test private methods. In general, you test the behavior of the first public method that relies on the private.

If you feel that you need, then it may be the case where the method should not be private.

This rule doesn't have to be applied blindly, but it's good to keep it in mind.

Comment: That breaks exactly the condition of my question. After that monkey patch my tests will not break if other parts of my code within 'lib/' use private calls but break on production.

Comment: You can wrap the class in a proxy, but it will be way more complex that just using `send :foo`. You don't have much alternatives. You either change the scope for a specific process, or use `send`

Comment: Avoiding implementation details is not always possible. For example in my `Service` I might never want to provide a count, or a custom query. However if I avoid that implementation detail I will have lots of unnecessary boilerplate about the database configuration

Comment: One way was using refinements within the RSpec module, which will expose private methods inside expect(...) calls. But could not find a way to do it easy and reuse it with my console

Comment: Refinement are experimental. The way you achieve it in Ruby is generally via `send`. Frankly speaking, it seems to me you are trying to *cargo cult* to Ruby the habit from another language.